# Showing figure inside figure environment in draft mode

Tags: graphics, floats, draft

I am writing the supporting information of a paper whose template can be downloaded [here](https://www.agu.org/-/media/Files/Publications/April-30-2019-latex-templates.zip?la=en&hash=EFE7EE17A9BF5A1B87FD52783AE87B8A59242C00)

Basically, it is in draft mode :

```
\documentclass[draft, grl]{agutexSI2019}
```

But I also add after this:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
%
%  Uncomment the following command to allow illustrations to print
%   when using Draft:
\setkeys{Gin}{draft=False}
%
```

As a result, figures outside figure environment (those not floats) show:

```
\includegraphics[scale = 1]{dummyfig.pdf}
```

but those inside figure environment doe not:

```
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[scale = 1]{dummyfig.pdf}
  \caption{test}
  \label{Figure_sand_pile}
\end{figure}
```

Any hint ?

Answer (score 1):

The class does

```
\ifjdraft%
\expandafter\ifx\csname setkeys\endcsname\relax\else
\setkeys{Gin}{draft=false}\fi
```

so sets the graphics back to draft mode in at least a couple of places

Probably you can do this:

```
\makeatletter
\setkeys{Gin}{draft=false}
\define@key{Gin}{draft}[true]{}
\makeatother
```

so you disable the key after setting it the way you want, further uses of `draft=anything` do nothing.

Comment: It does not makes floating figures appear :/ To be sure, I typed :

\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\setkeys{Gin}{draft=false}
\define@key{Gin}{draft}[true]{}
\makeatother

Comment: @Liris hmm you didn't supply a test file (questions should always have a test file, you can use `example-image` as the image) so this was untested but as far as I could see that should work.  An alternative, would be to simply edit your local copy for the class and  comment out every use of `\setkeys{Gin}{draft}`